# javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory' when using WebTestClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-webflux

I am trying to write an integration test with WebTestClient that will only standup the controller I'm testing with a WebTestClient to make the requests. On starting a test, I get this in the console:

```
14:33:50.435 [main] INFO org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.9.Final
14:33:50.442 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers - Cannot find javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath. Assuming non JPA 2 environment. All properties will per default be traversable.
14:33:50.457 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean - Failed to set up a Bean Validation provider
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
```

I can start the app as normal and everything works fine. Here's my test setup:

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Subject

class LocationControllerSpec extends Specification {

        @Subject
        private LocationController controller

        private LocationService service

        private WebTestClient testClient

        def setup() {
            service = Mock(LocationService)
            controller = new LocationController(service)

            testClient = WebTestClient.bindToController(controller).build()
        }

        def 'should work'() {

            Flux<List<Foo>> serviceResponse = Flux.just([bar])

            given: 'We expect the service to respond with a Location'
            service.getThing(a, b, c) >> serviceResponse

            expect: 'we should get a bar back'
            testClient.get().uri('/bar)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                        .exchange()
                        .expectStatus().isOk()
        }
    }
```

And here are my gradle.build dependencies:

```
ext {
    javaVersion = '1.8'
    springIoVersion = 'Cairo-RELEASE'

    // Dependency versions NOT in Spring IO Platform
    dseJavaDriverVersion = '1.5.1'
    resilience4jVersion = '0.12.0'
    spockVersion = '1.1-groovy-2.4'
    cglibVersion = '3.2.0'
    cassandraUnitVersion = '3.3.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.datastax.dse:dse-java-driver-core:${dseJavaDriverVersion}"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin"
    compile "io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-all:${resilience4jVersion}"
    compile "io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-reactor:${resilience4jVersion}"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

    runtime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:${spockVersion}"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-spring:${spockVersion}"
    testCompile "cglib:cglib-nodep:${cglibVersion}"

    integrationTestsCompile "org.cassandraunit:cassandra-unit-spring:${cassandraUnitVersion}"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I needed to have a javax.el added to classpath. Spring includes javax.el-api, but not an el. Added `compile "org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.0"` and it worked.